# Can Twilio save a voicemail in MP3 format when using the AWS S3 external storage option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, twilio, mp3

Twilio offers a handy setting to automatically store the voicemail recording file on AWS S3 (instead of Twilio servers). By default Twilio offers a recording in both .wav and .mp3 format however when using the S3 storage only the .wav is exported. Is there a way to tell Twilio to export the .mp3 instead (or in addition) to the .wav?

There is no settings/options to change this that I could find and the documentation for this feature is very minimalistic.

[Twilio Voice Recording External Storage settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s7Qi.png)